# Agregar "/" Slash al final de URL pero que no afecete a CSS y JS

Tags: .htaccess

tengo un problema recientemente realice un sitio en "Laravel" para poder seguir aprendiendo, el tema es que este no viene con "slash" al final de las url por ej:

```
tuweb.com/seccion1
```

esto lo solucione con .htaccess

ingresando lo siguiente:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Si bien ahora las urls con

```
tuweb.com/seccion1/
```

el problema esta con los CSS y JS que se les agrega tambien el / al final y no los lee.

Es decir que quedan asi.

```
tuweb.com/css/style.css/
```

Y no pueden ser leidos.

Si me pueden dar ayudar con alguna regla de excepción les agradezco.

Comment: Que parte no se entiende, disculpa posiblemente use muchas palabras para marcar que solucione y que problema genera al solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

modificando un poco lo que tienes, lo haría de esta forma:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{ENV:BASE}/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Prueba y me cuentas, podrías omitir lo del ENV base pero te puede ayudar si por alguna razón tu sitio se monta en un subdirectorio.